# How to control bad thoughts about sex, swearing, etc.?

Tags: practical-islam, evil-thoughts

For the last year or so I have been struggling with keeping focus due to my thoughts, they are very bad thoughts like sex, and swearing.  How can I control these thoughts?

I try to stop my mind but it keeps happening and throughout the whole time it is happening, I am trying to stop it but I can't. It also has stopped me from being able to pray without thinking of this, and read Quran, or even simpler tasks like doing work.

I really do not enjoy these thoughts and imaginations and they are taking control of me.

Answer (score 1):

1.Simply red quran.It will help a lot.(I think the most important part).

2.Decrease your connection with your bad friends.

3.Pray after a short while after Azan.

4.Go to a mosque to pray.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to stop thoughts will only give them more power. The trick is to relax your mind and practice not identifying with the thoughts. In other words, let them be there like images on a TV screen, while retaining conscious awareness of the vastness of the cosmos. When a thought is not engaged, through either being grasped at or resisted, it tends to lose its power and will gradually be replaced by more wholesome and helpful thoughts. This is not a magic bullet to shoot down the thought of this moment, but a long-term practice that will serve you well in many areas of your life.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE. Please consider taking your time to learn more about our site and the stack exchange model by taking our [tour] and visiting our [help].